# Let use a button all available width in SwiftUI on MacOS AppKit

Tags: macos, swiftui, appkit

I want to define a layout like this:

[image]

How can I let the Buttons grab all the available width, also when the user resizes the Window.
In the upper part three rows of equal width, in the lower part one row with max. width

```
struct TEST: View {
  let columns = [
    GridItem(.flexible()),
    GridItem(.flexible()),
    GridItem(.flexible())
  ]
  let data = ["1 Text ...",
              "2 longer Text ...",
              "3 Text ...",
              "4 Text/FA/Tra ...",
              "5 Text ...",
              "6 Text ...",
              "7 Text ...",
              "8 Text ...",
              "9  Text ...",
  ]

  var body: some View {
    VStack (alignment: .leading ){
      LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
        ForEach(data, id: \.self) { item in
          Button(action: {print("")}){
            Text(item).background(Color.green)
          }
          .background(Color.yellow)
        }
      }
      .padding(.horizontal)
    }
    Button("even longer Text"){print("x")}
    Button("even longer Text"){print("x")}
    Button("even longer Text"){print("x")}
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use `UIScreen.main.bounds.width/height` to get the dimensions of an iPhone. Maybe that works on MacOS, too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)`:

```
Button("even longer Text") { 
    print("x") 
}
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
```

---

**EDIT**

Here is a more detailed example:

```
var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
            ForEach(data, id: \.self) { item in
                Button(action: { print("") }) {
                    Text(item)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .contentShape(Rectangle())
                }
                .background(Color.yellow)
            }
        }
        .padding(.horizontal)
        .background(Color.blue)
    }
    Button(action: { print("x") }) {
        Text("even longer Text")
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .contentShape(Rectangle())
    }
    .background(Color.purple)
    ...
}
```

I added colors, so you can see that buttons are aligned properly.

[image]

Tested with Xcode 12.3, macOS 11.1

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Anything else to do?

Comment: @mica I added a more detailed example with background colors.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now the layout works fine - One thing left: it seems, that only the small part of the text inside the Button is clickable, which is not the expected behavior for a Button. Any Idea, how to fix that?

Comment: @mica You need to add `.contentShape(Rectangle())` - see the updated answer.

Comment: Hm .... Hope I´m not doing something wrong, but it it's the same with .contentShape(Rectangle()).  I copied your whole new code - only the text is clickable

Comment: @mica I checked my code again and it's working for me: macOS 11.1, Xcode 12.3. What is your environment?

Comment: BugSur 11.1 Xcode Version 12.3 (12C33). What else could be different?

Comment: @mica Hard to say, the code above should work on all platforms.

Comment: `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)` doesn't work for me on macOS (11.4) either, a button sticks to its intrinsic size. (works neither within the label, nor outside of the button). Something that works is giving the label a _fixed_ size (via `.frame(width: 120)`, which you could pass in using a GeoReader). I filed FB9335111

Comment: This was something that has broken recently in the iOS 15 betas. My buttons used to expand to fill in the column they where in, but now they just take their intrinsic size which is incredibly irritating.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

```
struct TEST: View {

  let columns = [
    GridItem(.flexible()),
    GridItem(.flexible()),
    GridItem(.flexible())
  ]
  let data = ["1 Text ...",
              "2 longer Text ...",
              "3 Text ...",
              "4 Text/FA/Tra",
              "5 Text ...",
              "6 Text ...",
              "7 Text ...",
              "8 Text ...",
              "9  Text ...",
  ]

  var body: some View {
    VStack (alignment: .leading ){
      LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
        ForEach(data, id: \.self) { item in
          ExpandingButton(s: item){print("pressed")}
        }
      }
      .padding(.horizontal)
    }
    ExpandingButton(s: "Hogo"){print("hogo")}
    ExpandingButton(s: "Hogo"){print("hogo")}
    ExpandingButton(s: "Hogo"){print("hogo")}

  }
}

struct ExpandingButton: View {
  var s : String
  var action: ()->Void

  var body: some View {
    HStack (alignment: .top){
      Spacer()
      Text(s)
       .padding(4)
      Spacer()
    }
    .background(Color.gray)
    .cornerRadius(4)
    .onTapGesture  {action()}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `frame(maxWidth: .infinity)` command. However, the trick is to **apply the width style to the label of the button itself** as opposed to the actual button declaration.

Here is a sample code on how to do this in Swift UI

```
Button {
    doSomething()
} label: {
    Text("Click me").frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
}
.buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
```

[source](https://sarunw.com/posts/swiftui-button-style-width/)