# SwiftUI Button, that expands and accepts keyboard-shortcuts in AppKit

Tags: swiftui, keyboard-shortcuts, appkit

I need to construct a layout like this and the Buttons shall accept keyboard-shortcuts (AppKit):
[image]

In [Let use a button all available width in SwiftUI on MacOS AppKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65563094/let-use-a-button-all-available-width-in-swiftui-on-macos-appkit) I found a solution, which creates the layout, but this ExpandingButton doesn't accept keyboard-shortcuts -maybe because it's an HStack.

Another idea, which was proposed in the post above to give a standard Button a .frame(maxWidth: .infinity) modifier did not work for me.

```
struct TEST: View {

  let columns = [
    GridItem(.flexible()),
    GridItem(.flexible()),
    GridItem(.flexible())
  ]
  let data = ["1 Text ...",
              "2 longer Text ...",
              "3 Text ...",
              "4 Text/FA/Tra",
              "5 Text ...",
              "6 Text ...",
              "7 Text ...",
              "8 Text ...",
              "9  Text ...",
  ]

  var body: some View {
    VStack (alignment: .leading ){

      LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
        ForEach(data.indices, id: \.self) { index in
          ExpandingButton(text:data[index],action: {print("pressed \(index)")})
          .keyboardShortcut(KeyEquivalent(Character(UnicodeScalar(0x0030+index)!)) , modifiers: [.command])
        }
      }
      }
      .padding(.horizontal)
    }
    ExpandingButton(s: "Hogo"){print("hogo")}
    ExpandingButton(s: "Hogo"){print("hogo")}
    ExpandingButton(s: "Hogo"){print("hogo")}

  }
}

struct ExpandingButton: View {
  var s : String
  var action: ()->Void

  var body: some View {
    HStack (alignment: .top){
      Spacer()
      Text(s)
       .padding(4)
      Spacer()
    }
    .background(Color.gray)
    .cornerRadius(4)
    .onTapGesture  {action()}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put `ExpandingButton` content in a Button, then `keyboardShortcut` will work as expected:

```
struct ExpandingButton: View {
    var s: String
    var action: () -> Void

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: action) {
            HStack(alignment: .top) {
                Spacer()
                Text(s)
                    .padding(4)
                Spacer()
            }
        }
        .background(Color.gray)
        .cornerRadius(4)
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can remove `ExpandingButton` and just use a *standard* `Button`:

```
VStack(alignment: .leading) {
    LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
        ForEach(data.indices, id: \.self) { index in
            Button(action: { print("pressed \(index)") }) {
                Text(data[index])
            }
            .keyboardShortcut(KeyEquivalent(Character(UnicodeScalar(0x0030 + index)!)), modifiers: [.command])
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        }
    }
    .padding(.horizontal)
    ...
}
```